# Добавление нового репозитория в ansible скрипте

Tags: linux, ansible, devops, kubernetes

Мне надо выполнить следующий набор команд с помощью `ansible`:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
apt-get update
apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

Проблемы начинаются со второй строчки. Через ansible делаю так:

```
- name: curl curl
  command: sudo curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

В ответ получаю ошибку:

```
 [WARNING]: Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather
than running sudo

fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["sudo", "curl", "-s", "https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg", "|", "sudo", "apt-key", "add", "-"], "delta": "0:00:00.037295", "end": "2018-02-14 07:25:50.272885", "failed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2018-02-14 07:25:50.235590", "stderr": "curl: option -: is unknown\ncurl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information", "stderr_lines": ["curl: option -: is unknown", "curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Как выполнить такую команду правильно? Пробовал добавить строку `sudo: true` и убрать `sudo` в команде. Ошибка не пропадает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот как-то так наверное:

```
- name: Install Kubernetes 4 Ubuntu
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
  become: yes
  block:
    - apt:
        name: apt-transport-https
        state: latest
    - apt_repository:
        repo: deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-{{ ansible_distribution_release }} main
        state: present
        filename: kubernetes
        update_cache: no
    - apt_key:
        url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
        state: present
    - apt:
        update_cache: yes
        force: yes
    - apt:
        name:
          - kubelet
          - kubeadm
          - kubectl
        state: present
        install_recommends: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Давайте по-порядку. Это всего лишь warning, предупреждение. Ansible предлагает вам переделать вашу баш команду, потому что видит в ней слово sudo и говорит вам "эй, я тоже умею sudo – используй мой штатный способ".

Можно проигнорировать.

Если же хочется использовать штатные возможности ansible - то вам нужно смотреть в сторону become:

```
---
# This playbook deploys 'webserver' server.

- include: init_server.yml

- name: deploy 'webserver'
  hosts: '{{ target | default("webservers") }}'
  become: true
  become_user: root
  roles:
    - nginx
    - httpd
    - { role: webtatic_repository, when: r_php.version == "5.6" }
    - php
```

При этом в ansible.cfg вы указываете, каким пользователем подключаться к машинам (у меня не все плейбуки требуют become_user: root), например:

```
[defaults]
sudo_flags=-HE
remote_user = ansible
retry_files_enabled = false
```

Чисто для истории: раньше команды become не было, использовался remote_user в сочетании с sudo, поэтому если столкнётесь с очень старыми статьями, то можете увидеть в них эту команду:

```
---
# This playbook deploys 'webserver' server.

- name: deploy 'webserver'
  hosts: '{{ target }}'
  remote_user: user
  sudo: true
  roles:
    - nginx
```

В моей практике был один случай, когда я проигнорировал предупреждение ansible о замене shell-команды rsync на модуль rsync ansible: я сначала написал именно task, использующий штатную команду rsync от ansible, но оказалось, что она не поддерживала некоторые режимы/ключи, которые поддерживались команд лайн rsync'ом. Поэтому я отдельно в комментариях описал причину такого нештатного скрипта, чтобы кто-нибудь не сломал скрипт, пытаясь его "улучшить" – но в целом стараюсь минимально использовать запуск из командной строки.

В вашем случае я бы рекомендовал перейти на [apt_repository](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/apt_repository_module.html) без игр с командной строкой.

Comment: Минусовать не буду, но у автора проблема не с warning – его можно проигнорировать, а в том, что он с модулем `command` использует пайпы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но, как заметили выше, это не устраняет ошибку с пайпом и до сих пор нет понимания как заменить `command` на более правильное решение.