# Как скачать и установить программу через wget на ubuntu в ansible?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible

Мне необходимо выполнить такие команды:

```
    wget -q -O- 'https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc' | sudo apt-key add -
    echo deb https://download.ceph.com/debian-{ceph-stable-release}/ $(lsb_release -sc) main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ceph.list
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt -y install ceph-deploy
```

Как я могу это сделать в `ansible` без использования `command` команды через `get_url` (на сколько я понимаю)?

Comment: По аналогии с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/785322/191416

Comment: Apt key adv наверное лучше

Comment: @eri, ему же на ансибле надо переписать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приблизительно как то так:

```
- hosts: ceph
  vars: 
    ceph_stable_release: 1234
  tasks:
  - name: Add key
    apt_key:
      url: https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc
      state: present

  - name: Add repository
    apt_repository:
      repo: "https://download.ceph.com/debian-{{ ceph_stable_release }}/ {{ ansible_distribution_release }} main"
      state: present

  - name: Install package
    apt:
      name: ceph-deploy
      update_cache: yes
      state: present
```